# Most productive days to work from home

Tags: work-environment, work-life-balance

Currently I have one work from home day - Wednesday. Changing this day is not an option. I have been allowed one extra work from home day. Are there known days that are most productive to work from home ?

Or does this just depend on the person ?

Comment: friday.  do not.  no regrets.

Comment: @easymoden00b do not work from home on friday ?

Comment: Which day has the worst traffic when you commute? That's when you should work from home.

Comment: With this question you may as well ask who likes the colour blue.  Some people are more productive on different days as it's completely a personal preference.  Voting to close as primarily opinion based!!

Comment: @JaneS Actually, I disagree. There have been studies on various work factors (such as the color of the walls, etc) about what is the most productive. As remote work becomes more common, it may be that there are factors you can use to determine more productive days to work from home.

Comment: @corsiKa My point is that those studies still give _statistical_ data for productive days.  Those data, while potentially indicative, still don't say for a particular _person_ which day they would prefer.  However, given I am a big fan of stats and their predictive qualities, it certainly would be more _likely_ for a person to reflect the averages (assuming breadth and size of the sample population is sufficiently wide and large) :)

Comment: *Are there known days that are most productive to work from home ?* Sure. It's the day with the most meetings. Dial in to those meetings. Know when it's your turn to talk. When it's not your turn to talk, do something productive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would depend on many factors such as:

- Are there tasks you do on certain days that need other people's
  input? Those are probably not the best days to work from home
- Do you have a lot of scheduled meetings that can easily be handled
  through teleconferencing? If 2/3 of Thursday is meetings that can
  easily be accomplished on teleconferencing, that might be a good
  day.
- Do you have some tasks you find easier to do at home when you are
  less distracted by people coming through? The day you do the majority
  of those tasks is a good candidate.
- Do you hate getting up on Mondays especially after the weekend and
  would appreciate the extra time to sleep in?
- Do you have a day when your regular evening plans would benefit from
  not having the extra time to commute?
- What is your spouse's schedule? Is there a day when you need to be
  home earlier for the kids so your spouse can work later?
- What other things are going on at your house during the week? If you
  spouse works from home on Friday would it be more disruptive to the
  home office set-up for both of you to be home?
- Would your anticipation of the weekend, make it more likely you would
  slack off at home on a Friday?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there known days that are most productive to work from home ?
>
> Or does this just depend on the person ?

I know of no days that would be "most productive to work from home" across companies, and across industries.

It probably depends a lot on the individual's self control. If you are concerned that you would treat a Monday or Friday as an extended weekend rather than real work days, then avoid them. You don't want to be viewed as a slacker.

But even more important is the company and the work environment.

In my company, Friday was a typical work-from-home day for many. Thus, there were very few important meetings scheduled for Fridays. Everyone seemed to understand that on Friday's you might not find the person you needed at their desk - thus you scheduled around it.

Check out your company and look for cultural scenarios like that. You might find a day where far fewer meetings would need your attendance. Those are signs for good choice days. You might find days where not being in the office would be burdensome for many others. Those are signs for bad choice days.

Answer (score 0):

According to Business Daily and Accounttemps, tuesday is the most productive day of the week. Thursday and friday's are the least productive days of the week. In order of productivity from most productive to least productive:

**Tuesday
Monday
Wednesday
Thursday 
Friday**

sources: http://www.businessnewsdaily.com/5637-the-most-productive-day-of-the-workweek-may-surprise-you.html, http://www.al.com/business/index.ssf/2014/01/new_us_survey_suggests_tuesday.html

A portion of productivity can be associated with how you look at the week. Tuesday being the day preceding the 50% mark of the week there tends to be the greatest push. Many people tend to get a bit lax after Wednesday. This would apply even in a work from home scenario; but you have to be sure to manage yourself well and minimize distractions.